# Regarding Google Speech API

Tags: c++, google-speech-api

I am using Google Speech API to convert voice to text convertion, it is working fine when i use my own recorded voice,
but the result is not proper while using computer generated Lady voice, like cell phone network operator voice.
Any one faced this kind of problem? or any one having solution for this? please help me to solve this issue...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set proper sampling rate `sampleRateHertz` of the speech?
Did it return something close, but not correct, or it totally failed with no speech at all? If you didn't get anything converted then verify that you sent correct info to speech api.

Comment: Hi, It is giving correct result when i record my own voice, but when i use operator's lady voice it is giving problem,
Audio : "i can play music answer questions get the news and weather create to do this and much more"
Result Text: "awesome full music onto questions to permission level created us so much more"

Comment: @ThirunavukkarasuS looks like it's problem in speech api, it cannot reliably convert it, since it converts it with errors, it's just happens. Shouldn't there be alternative conversions (I recall that they return that as well?)

Comment: Also, the API is quite sensitive to accents. for instance, using a language code of EN-US for a British speaker will give results that are far less accurate than when using EN-GB.